# TextsView null after code mysteriously runs twice

Tags: java, android

I have created an app which sends and receives text and displays the text in a textView. The app worked perfectly earlier and I can't seem to see why anything has changed but now i get a NPE when setting TextsView text. Funny thing is though that it shows as not null and sets correctly then for some unknown reason runs the same code again and this time the textview is null.

I know what a NPE is an why it happens. I just need help finding why the code runs twice and also why on the second time of running textsview is null.

Textsview is defined at the top of the class then set inside OnCreateView.

Class:

```
public class Rel1 extends Fragment {
    TextView textsView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rel1, container, false);
        getContext().registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
        textsView = view.findViewById(R.id.texts1);
        return view;
    }

public BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        String num = null, msg = null;
        if (bundle != null) {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                num = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                msg = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Log.d("SmsReceiver", "onReceive: Message Received = " + msg + " msgs = " + msgs + " bundle = " + bundle);
            Log.d("textsview", "onReceive: can SmsReceiver find texts view?" + textsView);
            setMsg(msg, num, textsView);
        }
    }
};
public void setMsg(String msg, String num, TextView textsView) {
        Log.d("SetMsg: ", "setMsg: msg = " + msg + " num = " + num);
        Log.d("texts view", "setMsg: is textsview existing? : " + textsView);
        if (textsView != null) {

            Log.d("setMSG", "setMsg: Function called" + msg);
            if (num.equals(txtPhoneNo.getText().toString()) || convNum(num).equals(txtPhoneNo.getText().toString())) {
                Log.d("setmsg: ", "setMsg: num checks out");
                if (msg.equals("REL 1 OFF==REL 2 OFF")) {
                    Log.d("Parse: ", "setMsg: REL 1 OFF==REL 2 OFF");
                    h = true;
                    w = true;
                } else if (msg.equals("REL 1 ON==REL 2 OFF")) {
                        Log.d("Parse: ", "setMsg: REL 1 ON==REL 2 OFF");
                        h = false;
                        w = true;
                    } else if (msg.equals("REL 1 OFF==REL 2 ON")) {
                            Log.d("Parse: ", "setMsg: REL 1 OFF==REL 2 ON");
                            h = true;
                            w = false;
                        } else if (msg.equals("REL 1 ON==REL 2 ON")) {
                                Log.d("Parse: ", "setMsg: REL 1 ON==REL 2 ON");
                                h = false;
                                w = false;
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Check Number! Incorrect Message Recieved!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
            }

            sendNotification(h, w);
            if(h && w) {
                textsView.setText(R.string.hON_wON);
                //((EditText)view2.findViewById(R.id.texts1)).setText(R.string.hON_wON);
            } else if (h && !w) {
                textsView.setText(R.string.hON_wOFF);
                //((EditText)view2.findViewById(R.id.texts1)).setText(R.string.hON_wOFF);
            } else if (!h && w) {
                textsView.setText(R.string.hOFF_wON);
                //((EditText)view2.findViewById(R.id.texts1)).setText(R.string.hOFF_wON);
            } else if (!h && !w) {
                textsView.setText(R.string.hOFF_wOFF);
                //((EditText)view2.findViewById(R.id.texts1)).setText(R.string.hOFF_wOFF);
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        getContext().unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getContext().unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        getContext().registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Logcat when sending correct message from correct number: 
Note how the code runs twice and textsview is there once and dead after

```
09-20 21:56:50.571 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/SmsReceiver: onReceive: Message Received = REL 1 OFF==REL 2 ON msgs = [Landroid.telephony.SmsMessage;@5bd4de0 bundle = Bundle[{format=3gpp, pdus=[[B@a949899, slot=0, phone=0, rTime=1537477010526, subscription=1, upload_flag=1}]
09-20 21:56:50.571 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/textsview: onReceive: can SmsReceiver find texts view?android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2156868 V.ED..... ........ 0,628-720,834 #7f0800b8 app:id/texts1}
09-20 21:56:50.572 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/SetMsg:: setMsg: msg = REL 1 OFF==REL 2 ON num = ###NUMBER OMMITTED
09-20 21:56:50.572 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/texts view: setMsg: is textsview existing? : android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2156868 V.ED..... ........ 0,628-720,834 #7f0800b8 app:id/texts1}
09-20 21:56:50.572 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/setMSG: setMsg: Function calledREL 1 OFF==REL 2 ON
09-20 21:56:50.594 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling finishReceiver: IIntentReceiver=38d2555
09-20 21:56:50.635 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/SmsReceiver: onReceive: Message Received = REL 1 OFF==REL 2 ON msgs = [Landroid.telephony.SmsMessage;@936fb6a bundle = Bundle[{format=3gpp, pdus=[[B@aff885b, slot=0, phone=0, rTime=1537477010526, subscription=1, upload_flag=1}]
09-20 21:56:50.636 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/textsview: onReceive: can SmsReceiver find texts view?null
09-20 21:56:50.636 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/SetMsg:: setMsg: msg = REL 1 OFF==REL 2 ON num = ###NUMBER OMMITTED
09-20 21:56:50.636 11037-11037/com.mypackage.myprogram D/texts view: setMsg: is textsview existing? : null
```

Can anyone give a reason for it running twice from one message and also for textsView to be null on the second time?

Comment: What do you mean code runs twice? Do you create new fragment when running it again? Do you unregister your receiver properly?

Comment: 1. try to make textView static please
2. is the Broadcast event ricing internally or outside?

Comment: You should add logging in `onCreateView`, log the intent (it could be invoked twice on two different actions), and should you unregister your receiver when you're done with it.

Comment: @HovanesMosoyan When trying to make it static Android studio warns me saying 'Do not place Android context classes in static field; this is a memory leak(an also breaks Instant Run)

Comment: @HovanesMosoyan I made it static and ran but it still changes from `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` to `null` in the second logs.

Comment: @Pawel The intent seems to be coming in twice as if statically registered in AndroidManifest as well, even though it isn't. That would also explain why i'm getting the null errors as its running from another place.

Comment: @Rel. Switcher please make the textsView app level static, the service may work when the main activity is in background

Answer (score 0):

Got it. In Rel 2 I was had set Texts view to R.id.textsview which doesn't exist, all I had to do was change it to R.id.texts1.